# SteamWebAPI IDOTA2Match_570 getScheduledLeagueGames

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

After I retrieved the results.

league_id | game_id | starttime | comment | final

these are the columns i received.

my question are, How to get the specific match winner results?

example: radiant_win = 1

and where do i use the "game_id" ? o_O

please i'd be glad if you answer this :(. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this example for your link: https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=27110133&key=

The source: http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=47115 (now available at http://web.archive.org/web/20140922070947/http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=47115)